# Trying to use Jcrop api

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jcrop

I am using Jcrop and I wan't to dynamically change the aspect ratio for the selection based on user input, so I guess the way to go is to use Jcrop api.

Thing is that if I use it as a jquery function it works ok:

```
$('#cropbox_full').Jcrop({
  onChange: update_full_dimensions,
  onSelect: update_full_dimensions
});
```

But if I use it calling Jcrop function my image is no longer displayed:

```
var api = $.Jcrop('#cropbox_full', options);
```

Is it a Jcrop bug?

BTW I am using chrome and jquery 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some bug while using chrome because in firefox this works:

```
$.Jcrop($('#cropbox_full'),options);
```

After jCrop has been setted it can be accessed like this and options can be resetted, this worked with chrome:

```
$('#cropbox_full').Jcrop(options);
var jcrop = $('#cropbox_full').data('Jcrop');
jcrop.setOptions(newOptions);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today. I solved it by initializing the Jcrop api in

```
$(window).load(function() { ... });
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

which is common practice in jQuery.

Comment: I had to put everything inside the load function. Thanks this solved my day.

Answer (score 2):

That could be a bug in JCrop but you can write your code in a fashion that works on Google Chrome, FF, IE and Safari. To do so, instead of:

```
        $.Jcrop($('#cropbox_full'),options);
```

use something like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#cropbox_full').Jcrop({
                onSelect: storeCoords,
                setSelect: [0, 0, 114, 137],
                aspectRatio: 114 / 137,
                minSize: [114, 137]
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `$.Jcrop()` directly, it's expecting a jquery object or an element.

A usage example would look like this:

```
$.Jcrop($('#cropbox_full'),options);
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug with chrome, according to the documentatio you could do: $.Jcrop('#cropbox_full',options); and if I remember correctly it does work with firefox.